# How to add termination condition to knapsack problem and how to show the graph?

Tags: python, graph, knapsack-problem

I'm new to python, I have this knapsack problem where there are items and their weight. The user will insert their priority (low-medium-high). And then the GA will then run to find the best backpacking list that maximizes the priority points without exceeding the maximum weight (30kg).

I did most of the genetic operators, except the termination condition (after 20000 generations or when the fitness reaches 1) did not work,and the graph (plot) of the GA's performance is not showing.

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import time
from unittest import result

# Data (search space)
items = {
    'Sleeping bag': 10,
    'Rope': 3,
    'Pocket Knife': 2,
    'Torch': 5,
    'Water Bottle': 9,
    'Glucose': 8,
    'First aid supplies': 6,
    'Rain jacket': 3,
    'Personal Locator Beacon': 2
}


Genome = list[int]
# Number of items
ITEMS_COUNT = len(items)

# # Number of points for the multi point crossover entered by the user. Default is 3
N_POINT = 3

# # Number of individulas in the population filled with some permutation of 0s and 1s entered by the user. Default is 50
POP_SIZE = 20

# # Elitisim for selection. Default is True
ELITISM = True

# # Number of generations entered by the user. Default is 200
GENERATIONS = 200

# # Crossover probability enterd by the user. Default is 0.1
CROSSOVER_PROBABILTY = 0.1

# # Mutate probability entered by the user. Defaulst is 0.05
MUTATION_PROBABITLY = 0.05

# Priorities
itemsPriorities = {'low': 5, 'medium': 10, 'high': 15}


# User input
def user_input():
    print('Welcome to Smart Hiker Backpacking!')
    print('Input your priority for items based on the priority legend: ')
    print('Low \t Medium \t High')
    print()
    print('Choose your priority for these items below: ')
    print('-'*50)  # design: ------
    for item, _ in items.items():  # Print items
        print(item)
    print('-'*50)  # design: ------

    prio_l = []

# Ask user to enter a priority for every item
    # Goes through and displays every item in the data (search space)
    for item in items:
        prio_input = str(input(f"What is your priority for {item}? "))
        while prio_input.lower() not in itemsPriorities.keys():  # convert entered data by the user to lower case

         # Asks the user again to enter a correct choice (low, medium, high), regardless of the capitalization
            prio_input = str(input('Please enter low, medium or high: '))
        else:
            prio_l.append(itemsPriorities[prio_input.lower()])
    return prio_l


priority_list = user_input()

# Print the item name and its entered priority
print('-'*50)  # design: ------
for i, j in enumerate(items):
    print(j, 'has a priority of: ', priority_list[i])


# Assume the population size is 20
pop_size = 20

# generate initial population


def create_initial_population(amount):
    #global pop_size
    return [generate_genome() for i in range(0, amount)]
# generate genome


def generate_genome():
    return [random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(0, len(items))]


print('-'*50)  # design: ------
#print("Population:\n", create_initial_population(POP_SIZE))

# Compute fitness function


def compute_fitness(target):
    total_points = 0
    total_weight = 0
    index = 0

    # Sum of priority points and weight
    for i in target:
        if index >= len(items):
            break
        if (i == 1):
            total_points += priority_list[index]
            total_weight += list(items.values())[index]
        index += 1

    # Cheking to fit
    if total_weight > 30:
        return 0
    else:
        return total_points


def get_total_points(pop):
    total_points = 0
    for target in pop:
        total_points += compute_fitness(target)
    return total_points


# mutating a point on a solution
def mutate(target):
    r = random.randint(0, len(target)-1)
    if target[r] == 1:
        target[r] = 0
    else:
        target[r] = 1

# selecting parents by using roulette wheel selection


def roulette_wheel_selection(pop, parent_number):
    parents = []
    total_points = get_total_points(pop)
    current_value = 0
    # spining the wheel and select parent based on rate of value and total_points
    for spin in range(0, parent_number):
        spin_value = random.randint(0, total_points)
        for target in pop:
            current_value += compute_fitness(target)
            if current_value >= spin_value:
                # print "SPIN!!! ,%s, TOTAL VALUE / SPIN VALUE : %s/%s, fit: %s" % (str(target),str(total_points), str(spin_value) , fitness(target))
                parents.append(target)
                pop.remove(target)
                total_points = get_total_points(pop)
                break
    # print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    return parents

# n-point crossover by using two solution to generate their child


def crossover(father, mother):
    # deciding the lines to split the solution
    genes_points = [0]
    genes_points += sorted(random.sample(range(2, ITEMS_COUNT), N_POINT))
    genes_points += [ITEMS_COUNT]
    child = []
    # creating a new child by using father and mother data
    for count in range(0, N_POINT+1):
        start = genes_points[count]
        end = genes_points[count+1]
        # chosing which part of father or mother
        if count % 2 == 0:
            child += father[start:end]
        else:
            child += mother[start:end]
    return child

# generating a new generation by mutation and crossover


def creating_new_generation(pop):
    # selection with roulette_wheel_selection
    new_generation = []
    parents = []

    if ELITISM:
        parents = pop[int(0): int(POP_SIZE/5)]
    else:
        parents = roulette_wheel_selection(pop, (POP_SIZE/5))

    parents_length = len(parents)
    new_generation.extend(parents[:])
    # mutating selected parents
    for p in parents:
        if MUTATION_PROBABITLY > random.random():
            mutate(p)
    children = []
    desired_length = POP_SIZE - parents_length
    # creating new children by using parents
    while len(children) < desired_length:
        # crossover cheking
        if CROSSOVER_PROBABILTY > random.random():
            # selecting two parents randomly
            father_and_mother = random.sample(range(0, parents_length-1), 2)
            father = parents[father_and_mother[0]]
            mother = parents[father_and_mother[1]]
            # crossover selected two parents to create a new child
            child = crossover(father[:], mother[:])
        else:
            # or cloning a parent randomly
            child = parents[random.randint(0, parents_length-1)][:]
        # checking to mutate the new child
        if MUTATION_PROBABITLY > random.random():
            mutate(child)
        children.append(child[:])
    new_generation.extend(children[:])
    return new_generation


def genome_to_string(genome) -> str:
    return "".join(map(str, genome))


def genome_to_items(genome, ITEMS):
    result = []
    for i, itm in enumerate(ITEMS):
        if genome[i] == 1:
            result += [itm]
    return result


def main():
    #start_time = time.time()
    population = create_initial_population(POP_SIZE)
    max_fit = 0
    for generation in range(1, GENERATIONS+1):
        plt.plot(generation, max_fit)
        plt.ylabel('Fitness')
        plt.xlabel('Generations')
        plt.show()
        #print("Generation %d with %d" % (generation, len(population)))
        population = sorted(
            population, key=lambda x: compute_fitness(x), reverse=True)

        for i in population:
            # print "%s, fit: %s" % (str(i), fitness(i))
            if compute_fitness(i) > max_fit:
                max_fit = compute_fitness(i)

        population = creating_new_generation(population)
    # for item in items:
        # print(item)
    #elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    #print( "Best: %s (%f)" % (genome_to_string(population[0]), compute_fitness(population[0])))
    print(
        f"The Best items for the customer backpacking:{(genome_to_items(population[0],items.items()))}")
    print("Maximum fitness: " + str(max_fit))
    #print ("Time : " + str(elapsed_time) + " seconds")



main()
```

Comment: Well, you aren't doing a `break` if the fitness reaches 1.  And you're doing a plot for each generation, which you will have to dismiss 200 times before the loop exists.  Did you intend to gather the fitness data in a list, and then do the plot after the loop exits?  If I make that change, your code completes very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If I change your main loop to this, it seems to work fine:

```
def main():
    population = create_initial_population(POP_SIZE)
    fit = []
    for generation in range(GENERATIONS):
        #print("Generation %d with %d" % (generation+1, len(population)))
        population = sorted(
            population, key=lambda x: compute_fitness(x), reverse=True)

        # First item in population has best fitness.
        fit.append( compute_fitness(population[0] ) )
        population = creating_new_generation(population)
    print(
        f"The Best items for the customer backpacking:{(genome_to_items(population[0],items.items()))}")
    print("Maximum fitness: " + str(max(fit)))
    plt.plot(fit)
    plt.ylabel('Fitness')
    plt.xlabel('Generations')
    plt.show()
```